# Cause for crash "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException from dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass"?

Tags: apk

I have seen a few posts about dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass but their stack traces are quite different. This crash is very rare but it does happen occasionally. It does not seem to be related to any code of the app because the stack trace does not show any of the app's code:

```
Crash details
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6445)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:5987)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5902)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:200)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1656)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6718)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by y0.c: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize (AppInitializer.java:242)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize (AppInitializer.java:206)
  at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate (InitializationProvider.java:45)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1920)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1895)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6440)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer
  at java.lang.Class.classForName
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:378)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize (AppInitializer.java:224)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

It looks like related to app installation. This particular one occurred on a Skyworth Metz 2k TV. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Is the dependency `androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller` directly or indirectly included in your project? This is the library that includes `androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer`.

Comment: @Robert I did a global search for "androidx.profileinstaller" but could not find any instance in the app project. The app uses a lot of androidx dependencies.